# Regular expression to match a certain number of digits anywhere in a string

Tags: regex, angularjs

I'm trying to use angular's ng-pattern attribute to enforce that the text in an input box matches a particular regular expression. I'm doing this for form validation. The input I'm using this on is a phone field. The phone field can accept 10 digit phone numbers but I don't want to require a specific format from my users other than it must contain a 10 digit number in there somewhere. So these would both be valid.

- 555-555-5555
- (555) 555-5555

On the backend, I would just remove all formatting and store the raw digits. In the past for this what I've done is to remove all non-numeric characters and then just made sure the length == 10. It's simple enough to do in a couple of lines of code, but is it something regular expressions can handle? This isn't something I've ever tried to make a regular expression do. I don't want to support specific formats because I don't care if they accidentally enter an extra space or if they want to type their phone number like this: 55-55-55-55-55. It really doesn't matter to me, I just want the regex to match if there are 10 digits and no more somewhere in the string.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: [`^(?:\D*\d){10}\D*$`](https://regex101.com/r/dR0kS6/1)?

Comment: Why don't you allow allow only numbers and then apply a consistent format such as in this [kendo UI masked textbox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index) example. This way the user doesn't have to apply formatting and you always know exactly what format you're going to receive.

Comment: For @stribizhev's approach I think [`(\d\D*?){10}`](https://regex101.com/r/nE7pE1/1) is better.

Comment: nice @Shadowen I should have thought to do a repeated capturing group. Put this as the answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Unfortunately, @stribizhev is correct. With > 20 numbers in the field, the regex captures two separate groups on one line. You will need a slightly more complex regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To allow just 10 digits in a string with a regex, no more no less, you can use

```
^(?:\D*\d){10}\D*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR0kS6/4) (`\D` replaced with `[^\d\n]` to exclude newline for demo only).

The [`(\d\D*?){10}`](https://regex101.com/r/nE7pE1/2) regex will find the match in a string with more than 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:.*?\d){11,})[^a-zA-Z\n]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iQ4nW0/1

Answer (score 0):

You can make attribute type directive for it and set validity with dynamic regular expression.